# Eclipse RCP product export using a certain JDK

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, java-8, export, eclipse-rcp

My Eclipse Mars 4.5.1. uses **JDK 8** to start-up (specified in the `eclipse.ini`)

My RCP project uses **JDK 7**. The entire workspace uses 7. I've also included the **JavaFX** JAR until I migrate the whole project to JDK 8, where I won't need it.

When I try to export the RCP project using the `.product` file, the exported version has some logs saying that certain classes using JavaFX have compile errors. Even though the exported version is started with JDK 7 (specified in the `.ini` file), and the JavaFX JAR surely was exported too, these UI components crash.

- This whole process works with Eclipse starting with JDK 7 !
- I really want to use my Eclipse with JDK 8, but ONLY the Eclipse
- How does Eclipse influence the export process? My target platform points to eclipse, but has JDK 7 set on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put a JRE 7 in your product location and test if it runs, remove the entry in the `.ini` file.

- plugins
- configurations
- **jre**
- ...

If this works, your entry in the `.ini` file is probably wrong.

Another thought: "I've also included the JavaFX JAR", where did you include it? Maybe you need to include it in the JRE.

Comment: The exported project ini file points to JDK 7, not 8. JavaFX JAR is manually copied from the JDK 7, into the buildpath of my project.

Comment: Yes, but can you try to copy the JRE into the product location. Just to test if the .ini could be the problem.

Comment: Is the JavaFX jar in the exported bundle? Is it defined in the build.properties?

Comment: Yes. The whole thing works when I open Eclipse with JDK 7. The only difference is the JDK path in the Eclipse ini, not even in the project!

Comment: I'm not talking about Eclipse launch, you say it does not work after you exported a product. After you exported your product, copy the JRE into your product location. Eclipse will automatically use the JRE if it is on the same level with the "plugins" and "configurations" directory.